# transformation matrix in 3D for structural analysing of framed elements

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code in Python for dynamic simulation of a 3D structure. Structure is consist of nodes and elements in different directions. 
I am trying to build up the stiffness matrix for the whole structure in global coordinate system with superposition of the element stiffness matrices. My problem is I need a general transformation matrix from local axis to global one for each of the elements. I've looked it up on the internet but most of the people make some assumption to make this transformation easier(e.g local y axis is in the global X-Y plane ...) which doesn't work for my problem.
I found a general way of calculating the transformation matrix but it needs a third node in the local coordinate system which is the thing that I don't know how should I find it.

I really appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: This is a little unclear to me - providing what code you have would be very helpful, IMO, towards clarifying. Are you unclear on how view transformation matrices work algebraically, or on how to implement matrices in python?

Comment: The code is too long, I can't copy it here. But my problem is how the transformation matrix works algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

Page 9 of this paper should maybe help: http://elvis.rowan.edu/~kay/papers/kinematics.pdf

First calculate the homogeneous transformation matrix for each element (relative to the global coordinate system). Then multiply it with the corresponding stiffness matrix to transform it into a global stiffness matrix.

Btw: 
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com or http://engineering.stackexchange.com are probably better communities for discussing that.

Comment: My problem is exactly how to find the transformation matrix for each element

Comment: Its explained in that paper